# Siri shows our website with www when we don't use that on iOs 12 suggested websites

Tags: no-www, search-results, ios

This question came about because of an issue with an SSL certificate on iOs. Basically, when you are on (in this case) an iPhone running iOs 12 and you go to the home screen search (spotlight? swipe left home screen search) and search for 'PHmuseum' our website appears within 'Siri suggested websites'. But the URL used is `www.phmuseum.com` and our website uses `phmuseum.com`. The `www` exists in DNS and we have a 301 redirect for it. I've recently corrected the SSL certificate to include `www` as iOs shows an error even on a 301 (which Chrome doesn't).

Where do these search results come from? It doesn't seem to be Google. Does anyone know how to manage these results for your website? I'd like to remove the `www` and explore other optimisations.

Comment: Siri uses Bing as search results. But I can't see anything strange in Bing. Maybe it was some temporary issue?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, but its been like that for a while.